# About the relocation table in DOS EXE header

Tags: dos, exe, portable-executable

[image]

From the above we can see **count of relocation table entries** is `0`(there is no reloc item), but **offset of first reloc item** shows that the reloc item actually exists.

The definition of DOS EXE Header is [here](http://www.frontiernet.net/~fys/exehdr.htm).

How to understand it?

Comment: The link is broken. It would have been nice if you included the important part of the referred link in the question itself (assume that links will sooner or later break).

Answer (score 1):

This is normal. For modern formats like PE, the offset to the relocation table is always 0040H, even if there are zero relocation items.

Comment: Does the relocation table take up any space if there's no items?

Comment: No, the relocation table doesn't take up any space if there are zero items. Take a look at the bytes at offset 0040H. You'll see the first machine instructions of the program.

Answer (score 0):

You have to look at the EXE header size (shown as `DOS_HdrSize` in your screenshot).  This is the number of paragraphs (16-byte blocks) that the whole header uses.

In your example it is `0x0004` so multiply it by 16 and you get the header length as `0x40` bytes.  The relocation table starts at the relocation table offset and continues for `DOS_ReloCnt` entries until the end of the header.

In your case the relocation table offset is `0x40` and the end of the header is also `0x40` thus there is no room for the relocation table, which is just as well since `DOS_ReloCnt` says there are zero entries in it.

In this case it probably does not matter what value the relocation table offset is set to.